# Order by date returns incorrect values

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT   likes, date
        FROM     statistics_pages
        WHERE    idnum = '".$_COOKIE['id']."'
          AND    page_name = '".$row_fpages['page_name']."'
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 7";
```

And it returns totally incorrect numbers (`likes`) it's like giving any value +500k extra and i have no idea why is that happening because when i remove `ORDER BY` the values are exact (but not ordered correctly).

EDIT with the table structure:

```
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idnum` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `page_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_id` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Eww, `$_COOKIE` value directly dumped to a query. -- Can you post some example data that's in the table as well?

Comment: Just to make sure. 1. is "date" a real DATE field, or just int with the timestamp? 2. try to use "`date`" ( with inverted commata) instead of "date" in your ORDER BY

Comment: @hsz - Why? 0_o, Col.Sharpnel - Edited with the structure.

Comment: @Ricardo $_COOKIE['id'] can be modified by the user and will be inserted directly into your table. Fix for the main problem, try to use backticks (`) beside the date field

Comment: @Ricardo you have to be careful what you put into SQL statement. Right now I can overwrite your cookie and set a part of sql query. YOu have to cast it to integer: `idnum = ".(int) $_COOKIE['id']."`

Comment: well, the database won't return the data that doesn't exists. check your data for these +500 rows. are there any stored procedures?

Comment: @hsz - Maybe i can store the cookie inside of a variable and use the variable in the query instead? @Col.Shrapnel - It returns the numbers because they Exist but if the value lets say `30104331` it turns it into `30601890` or something... and it's really weird. Also i have tried to add `backticks` on `date` and it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you rename this column? It would be better for you I think...

Comment: @greg0ire - changed and it doesn't help.

Comment: @Ricardo you don't understand basic PHP security please learn some.

Comment: @DampeS8N - buddy my question isn't about PHP security and SQL Injections so don't try to be smart with answers for questions i didn't asked. thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo. I didn't answer the question. I'm pointing out that the code you've given as an example would be trivially exploitable. Like, get you fired exploitable. If you are just learning PHP, please stop this project and learn security. Security isn't something you add to an application.

Comment: @DampeS8N - Ok, now please let's get back to the main question.

Comment: @Ricardo If your table really only has ~250 records, could you post a link to a dump of the whole thing?

Comment: Re date field, if backsticks don't work, prefix it with the name of the table or even its alias, it can't then be confused with anything

Comment: @gregory - I did that and also cleaned the data in this table a bit, and i works. Thanks bro. DampeS8N - Maybe you was on the right direction cause i cleaned the data a bit and it works now, i just has same dates for the same page and i think that maybe it was causing the problem.

Comment: -1, because security is not optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL-injection**

As explained your query has SQL-injection issues.

Rewrite the code to:

```
$idnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['id']);
$pagename = mysql_real_escape_string($row_fpages['page_name']);
$sql = "SELECT   likes, date
        FROM     statistics_pages
        WHERE    idnum = '$idnum'
          AND    page_name = '$pagename'
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 7";
```

For integers you can also use `intval()`, but I prefer one function for all my escaping.

Other than that there is nothing wrong with the query. The word `date` is **not** a mysql reserved word and does not need backticks.
See the list of reserved words here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

**Why your query is not working**
The problem is most likely bogus data in your table, remove the `limit 7` and study the output.
The query itself is 100% correct.

**Comments on your table**

```
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `idnum` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `page_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_id` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',   <<-- not recommended use `null` 
                                               <<-- for `no date` 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)  <<-- PK's are always unique, you can drop this.
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`int(5)` and `int(12)` is really the same 32-bit integer. It's just that int(5) will only display 5 digits.