# What is the proper way to secure data going in & out of my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to secure my script a bit after some suggestions in [the last question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997119/order-by-date-returns-incorrect-values).

Do I need to secure things like `$row['page_name']` with the `mysql_real_escape_string` function? example:

```
$pagename = mysql_real_escape_string($row['page_name']);
```

I'm asking mainly because when I do secure every row I get some errors like when trying `number_format()` it throws `number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given` while when it is not secured with `mysql_real_escape_string` it works.

Can someone clear this for me? Do I only need to secure `COOKIE`'s or the row fetches too?

I got the suggestion in this post: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997119/order-by-date-returns-incorrect-values/8000819#8000819) (look at the selected answer)

Comment: can you show code where error is, not only one row ?

Comment: Please tell me what code you would like to see, i rather not post the Whole script cause it's really long with a lot of not related stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it backwards. Presumably `$row` is a row *coming out of* the database. You don't [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the way *out* of the database, you use it on data going *into* the database to prevent SQL injection. It prevents people from submitting data that contains executable SQL code.

Once the data is safely in the database, you're done with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (until you attempt to update that data). User data coming *out* of the database needs to be run through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before it hits the page to prevent script injection.

Basically, on the way to the database, *just before your insert/update runs*, you need to escape potentially executable SQL. On the way to the browser, *just before strings leave your app for the browser*, you need to escape potentially executable JavaScript and/or interpretable HTML. Escaping should be the last thing you do with a piece of data before it leaves your app for either the browser or database.

Comment: 1) So i can't define a variable for the secured value? 2) I need to use `html_special_chars` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string` when the data is pulled from the database?

Comment: 1) You can store the encoded value anywhere, it's just a value. Place it in a variable or an array. I made the assumption that your variable was coming from the database because you didn't specify. 2) Yes, using `mysql_real_escape_string` on data going to the browser will yield broken output and potential JS-injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means a complete answer.

Before writing any more code you need to stop and consider exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish.

In other words, what are you gaining by running the `mysql_real_escape_string` function?

Generally speaking, you escape data submitted by the client.  This is to help prevent sql injection.  Also, you should go further to actually validate that what the client sent in is acceptable (ie. "Sanity Check").  For example, if you are expecting a numeric entry, don't accept strings and range check the values.  If you are expecting string data like a name, don't accept HTML, but again range check to verify length is acceptable.  Both of these situations occur when the client submits data, not when you are writing it back out.

Going a little further, your cookies should be encrypted and marked with the httponly flag to tell the browser that it is not for use in client side script.  Even with that, you shouldn't trust the data in the cookie at all; so go ahead and run your sanity checks and still escape those values in queries.

I highly recommend that you go to the [OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org) and read through all of the issues to get a better understanding of how attacks work and how to defend against them.  Web App security is too important to just start coding without really knowing what's going on.

BTW, kudos to you for learning about this and trying to defend your site.  Too many devs don't even think about security at all.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting/updating a row where the values have come from untrusted sources.

This includes things like:

- $_GET
- $_POST
- $_COOKIE
- Anything that comes from the browser
- Etc..

You should only use it when putting things into the database, not when you are taking things out, as they should already be safe.

A safer way altogether is to use the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class

Answer (score 1):

If you use the PDO extension to build clean requests, you can create functions that will do this (secure strings and define their type) :

An exemple where $text is a string of text and $number is an integer :

```
public function InsertThis($number, $text) {
    $pdo = $this->getPdo();
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (number, text) VALUES (:number, :text");
    $sth->bindParam('number',$number,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam('text',$text);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` does not "secure" anything. It escapes characters that can be used in [sql injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Therefore the only values that you should escape are the ones supplied by your users. There should be no need to escape things that come out of your own database.

Comment: I have edited the post with the link to my previous question with the suggestion to do what I'm currently doing, any explanation of what the guy there suggested?